# Can I upgrade to Yosemite without a credit card?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, apple-id

I just bought a used iMac, and updated to 10.6.8 from 10.5.8.
I created my first Apple ID, and verified it. Now I am trying to update to Yosemite, so that I can install Xcode.  When I try to give my Apple ID it ends up telling me I need to give it credit card info. I do not own a credit card, for religious reasons, and I can't figure out how to update to Yosemite without it.

Comment: Usually, you can choose in the payment section "none". I've always done this to avoid adding a credit card

Comment: I have no option to select none. nearest apple store is 200mi away.

Comment: Then call the support, it's free and they are very helpful

Comment: can you post their number?

Comment: It's not the same one for every country, plus you managed to post here so I'm pretty sure you have the ability to type on google "apple support *your country* ". I'm willing to help, but not to do google search for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options that I can see:

- You can create a second Apple ID for the "purchase" (and any other free apps you want). All you need is another email address to link the second account to. Apple generally recommends using a single Apple ID for both iCloud and App Store, but it's not required, and since all you're "buying" is a free upgrade, it doesn't matter much which ID you use for the purchase.

  In order to get the "none" option for payment, you need to create the Apple ID while "buying" a free app (such as Yosemite). The full process is given in [Apple support document HT204034](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034), but here's the short summary:

  1. Open the App Store, and make sure you're not already signed into an Apple ID (if the Store menu has a "Sign Out" choice, use it).
  2. Find a free app (e.g. Yosemite), and click Get.
  3. In the Sign In dialog, click Create Apple ID.
  4. Follow the prompts to create the Apple ID; as long as you're creating it at this point, you should get the "none" option for payment.
  5. A verification email will be sent to the address you used for this ID. You need to click the "Verify Now" link in the email and sign in again before you can use the ID for the App Store.
  6. After all that, you have to go back to the App Store application, sign in with the new ID, and "Get" Yosemite.
- The other option, which might or might not be workable for you, is to borrow a friend's credit card for the setup process, then go into iTunes and change the payment type to "none" (see [Apple support document HT201266](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201266)). Note that while the card won't be charged (unless you buy something on it), a temporary authorization hold will be placed against it to verify its info.

Comment: Actually, I borrowed a friends AppleID. Hurray team work! Thanks for the assist @Gordon Davisson

Answer (score 1):

maybe the information in this link will help?

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034

Comment: Hi Res, please summarize the contents of the link.

Comment: Since you already created an AppleID, I believe you DO have to add a card, but can then remove it.  The other option is to create a new Apple ID.

You'll want to sign out of your current account, and then go download a free app or song or anything out of iTunes.  Then hit Create ID when it asks, and then proceed to choose 'None" when it asks for payment info.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.